# Why is my table not the same width as my tr

Tags: html, css, xslt, xls

I want to have a second table in my first table. 
How do I make the second table as wide as the TR of the first table?
To make the problem more visible I added some colors to the code.
Please excuse my chaos here its my first time trying HTML...

```
    <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;">
    <xsl:if test="NonOriginalArticlesCount">
        <xsl:for-each select="NonOriginalArticles/Mail_NewsletterArticle">
            <tr>
                <!--column picture-->
                <td rowspan="2" style="padding-top: 1.5em; ">
                    ...
                </td>
                <!--column name and desc-->
                <td colspan="3" style="padding-top: 1.5em;">
                    ...
                </td>
                <!--column price-->
                <td>
                ...     
                </td>
            </tr>
                <!--row alternative-->  
                <tr colspan="2">
                    <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    background:black;
                    backgound-color:black;
                    color:<xsl:value-of select="/Mail_Newsletter/Color"/>;
                    padding-bottom:1.5em;
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:attribute name="style">
                        background:yellow;
                        backgound-color:yellow;
                        color:<xsl:value-of select="/Mail_Newsletter/Color"/>;
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                            table-layout: fixed
                            width=100%;
                            border: 1px solid;
                            font-size:'14px';
                            border-collapse: collapse;
                            border-spacing: 0;
                            border-color: <xsl:value-of select="/Mail_Newsletter/Color"/>;
                            background:<xsl:value-of select="/Mail_Newsletter/LighterColor"/>;
                            backgound-color:<xsl:value-of select="/Mail_Newsletter/LighterColor"/>;
                            color:<xsl:value-of select="/Mail_Newsletter/Color"/>;

                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    ...
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>   
</table>
```

[image: The result]

Comment: add `width="100%"` as an attribute (or CSS style) to the inner table

Comment: to the tr? i already added it to the div and the table as you can see in the picture

Comment: Please show us the code?

Comment: Post your code directly in the question. Do not post images of code.

Comment: Also, `td` and `th` are the only valid children of a `tr`.

Comment: the Table html is malformed. TR inside TR? Colspan to TR?
maybe just replace the TR with TD

Comment: Sorry tried to fix the image problem as soon as i could...

Comment: @Blazemonger Ok thank you that's a start. So i have to take the tr out and put it underneath the other one right? And there is not way to put one table into another table? Did i understand this correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `td` (or `th`) can be a child of a `tr` element. Replace the `div` with a `td` and set the inner `table` to 100% width.

```
            </tr> <!-- close old table row before opening a new one -->
            <tr colspan="2">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    background:black;
                    backgound-color:black;
                    color:<xsl:value-of select="/Mail_Newsletter/Color"/>;
                    padding-bottom:1.5em;
                </xsl:attribute>
                <td> <!-- replaces div -->
                    <xsl:attribute name="style">
                        background:yellow;
                        backgound-color:yellow;
                        color:<xsl:value-of select="/Mail_Newsletter/Color"/>;
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <table width="100%">
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed the code to fit your adjustments but i still only get the table in the left column. I also updated the question to fit the new code. I hope that was correct.

Comment: Ok this helped a lot i figured the rest out by mylsef thank you very much!